# Is it possible to bring up Android keyboard via adb?

Tags: android, adb, android-softkeyboard

Is it possible to bring up the Android soft-keyboard by sending some kind of adb command?

Answer (score 1):

To show the keyboard:

```
adb shell input keyevent 108
```

to hide it:

```
adb shell input keyevent 111
```

But this only works if you're already focused on a view that is ready to receive text (like `EditText`).

Comment: But then I can also send coordinate click. Both are kind of messy solutions because you need an app with an EditText.

Comment: What is your use case? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Fix an wrong keyboard language on a remote Android device. Need to bring up the keyboard to see if my changed language setting took effect. I do that by taking a screenshot and sending home.